# From HTML form to SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I want to go from a HTML form to a SQL database using PHP.

Here is my current code:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitIpG']))
{

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO GmodServers (ipaddress)
VALUES ($_POST['submitIpG'])";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

echo "<br />\n";
}
```

As you can see it's hard coded with a specific IP. However, I want it to use an IP from the user input in my form.

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="value" name="submitIpG" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submitIpG" value="ADD"/>
</form>
```

How do I do this? I've tried things such as:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO GmodServers (ipaddress)
VALUES ('$_POST['submitIpB']')";
```

Without success.

Thanks!

Comment: you do not execute the query. Also please do not throw post variables in your query. Use prepared statements.

Comment: both your inputs bear the same name attribute

Comment: your query also failed

Comment: Good catch @Fred-ii- with the input names being the same

Comment: @Akintunde I don't really know what that means. I've also updated with more of my php code. It works with the hardcoded version, but that's not obviously useful for the website.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't really know how to connect the button with the text input so I tried by doing that, I've changed to to another name now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the action php script in form html also your inputs should be like

```
<form method="post" action="your_php_file.php">
<input type="text" name="submitIpG" placeholder="the ip input"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD"/>
</form>
```

and your_php_file.php should be like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO GmodServers (ipaddress)
VALUES ('$_POST['submitIpG']')";
```

But the most important part is DO NOT USE sql queries like that. Please consider using prepared statement. 
There is a good and simple example at w3school. this is the link you may want. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Thanks! What is "action" for? I read about it but I think it's used when you have PHP in a separate file. However, my php and html is in the same. I might be wrong though. I will read your link and try to understand prepared statements, I have no idea how to use them atm though.

Comment: if php and form are in same file, yes you're right. input names should be unique for your case. also could you share your file or do you get any errors ?

Comment: Yes, I get this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP-Source-Query-master\addData.php on line 18"

Comment: Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/5zfh9vYh Thanks for the help!

Comment: update your 18th line like this $sql = "INSERT INTO GmodServers (ipaddress) VALUES ('".$_POST['submitIpG']."')";

but you could update your core for prepared statements after testing this. have a coding.

Comment: I found a solution right before you posted this, changing it to: VALUES ('$_POST[submitIpG]')"; worked. Thanks for your help! I will try to move over to prepared statements next.